# Magento issue after patch update - product not getting added to cart and admin login not allowed

Tags: magento, warnings, patch

I am running Magento CE 1.9.

The issue is :

1. Products not getting added to cart
2. Admin login not allowed and show
   this error :

`[ Warning: include(Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/<path to web...>/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93`

`Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/...path to web.../app/code/local:/var/www/...path to web.../app/code/community:/var/www/...path to web.../app/code/core:/var/www/...path to web.../lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/...path to web.../lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93`

`Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/...path to web.../app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 244 ]`

When I clear the cache folder, these issues are solved, but again reappears after few hours !

I remember that I did a patch update 1533,5344,5994 and after few days got this issue, earlier this never happened. I just doubt on patch but may not be the fact.  I can solve this by running cron every hour to clear the cache, but this is not a permanent solution.

Can you please help, I cant figure this out.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Magento version is 1.9.2.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

After applying the patch, check the status of rights and permissions on folders and files.

Comment: I have run magtno cleanup utility to set proper permissions and clear caches - https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php, which set file permissions to 0644 and folder permissions to 0755 and doing this solves the problem, but after few hours it reappears.